# How to create main menu with the two buttons one will load the VR level (mode) and other will simple FPS (mode) so, how to get this?

Tags: unreal-engine4

Am working on unreal with interactive project and having two modes to play with one is simple FPS mode and another is VR mode so, i want to create a menu with two buttons one will start FPS mode and another will start a VR mode.

Comment: Create two maps and two game modes, then tied the respective game mode to its map. Use open level node in the widget blueprint (UI) to load the map when the button is pressed.